# java I/O & exceptions

Tags: java, object, java.util.scanner

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get my code to read a .dat file and use its contents to fill in the information. I am not too sure if my code below is the correct way on doing this.

The code won't run, but it will compile? Any thoughts I am using a macbook with Dr. Java.

UPDATE: So it's not the code, but was the software... just downloaded another java program, thank you all for the help i wouldn't have figured it out on my own!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Pay {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
    File file = new File("c:\\rate.dat");  
      Scanner input = new Scanner(file); 
  // I was not too sure if the last two lines are the correct ways to call the .dat file

      int id;
      String last;
      String first;
      double h![enter image description here][1]oursWorked;
      double rate;
      double total;

   for (int count = 1; count <= 4; count++) { //the file only needs to be ran 4 times 
         System.out.println("Employee I.D.: ");
         id = input.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Last Name: ");
         last = input.next();

         System.out.println("First Name: ");
         first = input.next();

         System.out.println("Hours Worked: ");
         hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();

         System.out.println("Hourly Rate: ");
         rate = input.nextDouble();   

         total = totalPay (hoursWorked, rate);

         System.out.println("\nEmployee ID  :" + id);
         System.out.println("\nLast Name    :" + last);
         System.out.println("\nFirst Name   :" + first);
         System.out.println("\nHours Worked :" + hoursWorked);
         System.out.println("\nPay Rate     :" + rate);
         System.out.println("\nTotal Pay    :" + total);
     }
  }
 //Total Pay
 public static double totalPay (double time, double r) {
        double total = 0.0;
         if (time <= 40.0) {
          total = (time * r);

         }
          else if (time > 40.0) {
            total = (((time - 40) * (r * 1.5)) + (40 * r));            
          }
     return total;
  }
 }
```

the rate.dat file contains:

```
1
Washington
Geroge
45
30
210
Jackson
Andrew
55
20.5
299
Obama
Barak
10
20
405
Reagan
Ronald
59
40
```

Comment: you should post the exception that you get

Comment: that's the problem, the code won't execute but it will compile?

Comment: Your code works fine... I have tried in my eclipse IDE

Comment: so its probably my software then?

Comment: `the code won't execute but it will compile?` that's unclear to me. If the code compiles than it gets executed. Get rid of `throws Exception` in the main and log the exception when it gets thrown with `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Hi,instead of using throws on main method..can you put try catch block and print  stack trace inside catch block and post it..it helps a lot to find the solution

Comment: let me try to post a screen shot of what i mean. I have restarted the computer, shows no errors when compiling it just won't execute?

Answer (score 3):

There is a little error in your code

```
double HoursWorked;
```

should be

```
double houseWorked;
```

Comment: sorry about that one, didn't catch all typos when typing here i'll change thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Pay.java as is is not compilable, because declared

```
(Error:(29, 14) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable hoursWorked
location: class Pay)

hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
```

I added the declaration

```
double hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
```

of it and it works with the following output on console:

```
Pay Rate     :20.5

Total Pay    :1281.25
Employee I.D.:
Last Name:
First Name:
Hours Worked:
Hourly Rate:

Employee ID  :299

Last Name    :Obama

First Name   :Barak

Hours Worked :10.0

Pay Rate     :20.0

Total Pay    :200.0
Employee I.D.:
Last Name:
First Name:
Hours Worked:
Hourly Rate:

Employee ID  :405

Last Name    :Reagan

First Name   :Ronald

Hours Worked :59.0

Pay Rate     :40.0

Total Pay    :2740.0
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Pay {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
    File file = new File("c:\\rate.dat");  
      Scanner input = new Scanner(file); 
  // I was not too sure if the last two lines are the correct ways to call the .dat file

      int id;
      String last;
      String first;
      double HoursWorked;
      double rate;
      double total;

   for (int count = 1; count <= 4; count++) { //the file only needs to be ran 4 times 
         id = input.nextInt();
         last = input.next();
         first = input.next();
         HoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
         rate = input.nextDouble();   
         total = totalPay (HoursWorked, rate);

         System.out.println("\nEmployee ID  :" + id);
         System.out.println("\nLast Name    :" + last);
         System.out.println("\nFirst Name   :" + first);
         System.out.println("\nHours Worked :" + HoursWorked);
         System.out.println("\nPay Rate     :" + rate);
         System.out.println("\nTotal Pay    :" + total);
     }
  }
 //Total Pay
 public static double totalPay (double time, double r) {
        double total = 0.0;
         if (time <= 40.0) {
          total = (time * r);

         }
          else if (time > 40.0) {
            total = (((time - 40) * (r * 1.5)) + (40 * r));            
          }
     return total;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Explain what in the world you're doing. Just copy pasting code is not an answer.

Comment: yes take care of the Nicolas words from next time..